# Populate user details facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

i'm trying to populate user details from the logged in session user in my app. The problem is that it seem to trigger the error message instead of the:

```
NSLog(@"%@", user.name);
NSLog(@"%@", [user objectForKey:@"id"]);
```

When i remove the

```
if (!error) { }
```

from the code it gives me answer (null) (null)

My question is why does it return null instead of the user.name and user.id??

appdelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {


        return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication fallbackHandler:^(FBAppCall *call) {

        if (call.accessTokenData) {
            if ([FBSession activeSession].isOpen) {
                NSLog(@"INFO: Ignoring app link because current session is open.");
            }
            else {
                [self handleAppLink:call.accessTokenData];
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

LoginViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self updateView];

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    if (!appDelegate.session.isOpen) {
        // create a fresh session object
        appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] init];


    if (appDelegate.session.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {

            [appDelegate.session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                         FBSessionState status,
                                                         NSError *error) {
                // we recurse here, in order to update buttons and labels
                [self updateView];

            }];
        }

    }

    [self populateUserDetails];

}

- (void)populateUserDetails {
            AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
        if (appDelegate.session.isOpen) {
            [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
             ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
                 if (!error) {
                     NSLog(@"%@", user.name);
                     NSLog(@"%@", [user objectForKey:@"id"]);
                 }
             }];

    }
}
```

The error message:

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0xc87b9f0 {com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 2500;
            message = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 400;
}, com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=400}
2014-01-26 15:09:49.486 Friendflirt[1125:70b]
```

Comment: And what about printing the error?

Comment: Sorry. its added now!